# Grouping algorithm based on distance

Tags: python-3.x

I have a set of 200 points with x and y coordinates. I need to make batches of 20 such that each point in the batch is "n" centimeters away from the other 19 i.e. no two points in one batch are within "n" cm of the other. A point should only belong to one batch. How do I solve this?

I've used trees to draw out branches such that a new node is added only if it is "n" cm away from all other nodes in the branch. This works but is extremely slow.

Input.csv: |Point Name||X coordinate||Y coordinate| 
Output: Lists of batches

Comment: Please show example input and output.

Comment: input - csv file - |Point name|x coordinate|y coordinate|

Comment: So I hope you can read csv files and also will be able to patch my answer for your specifc needs. If not, I need an csv file as example.

Comment: Can you please explain your process? I can work with the csv

Answer (score 0):

From what I guess from your question, this should to it:

```
import math
from random import randrange

test_data = {(randrange(0, 1000), randrange(0, 1000)) for _ in range(200)}

inf = float("inf")


def distance(p1, p2):
    return math.hypot(p2[0] - p1[0], p2[1] - p1[1])


def batch(data: set, min_distance, max_distance=inf, count=20, remove=True):
    result = [next(iter(data))]
    candidates = {t for t in data if max_distance > distance(result[0], t) > min_distance}
    while len(result) < count and len(candidates) > 0:
        result.append(candidates.pop())
        candidates = {t for t in data if all(max_distance > distance(p, t) > min_distance for p in result)}
    if len(result)<count:
        raise ValueError("Not enough values in data that have great enough distances between each other")
    if remove:
        data.difference_update(result)
    return result

print(len(test_data))
i = 1
while test_data:
    print(i,batch(test_data, 10))
    i+=1
```